# Closures outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, closures, nslayoutconstraint

I'd like to create a simple app without Storyboard. I've created a closure outside the `viewDidLoad` method, which represents a title on the screen. My problem is that the code contains duplicated lines  `view.addSubview(label)` and it positions the label to the wrong place.

Could you please help me solving this issue?

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.text = "Hello"
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to set the label at the center of HomeVC's view, the problem in the above code is that you are making a new view and place the label inside the view and thats not what you want , so

You just make label first like this:

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = {

            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            label.text = "Hello"
            return label
        }()
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` add this label as subview of view and apply constraints

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        setupTitleLabel()
}

func setupTitleLabel() {
        titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        //you also need to give the label height and width constraints to label here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, I just wanted to add minimal code in viewDidLoad.